# MYSQL Views on 3 Tables, Indexing and Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, view, sql-view

I have 3 tables which each contain over 3M records and are related to each other. Example: Table 1: **Student**

```
SELECT `dbName`.`id`, -- int
    `dbName`.`upload_dt`, -- datetime
    `dbName`.`end_of_dt`, -- datetime
    `dbName`.`name`, -- varchar(50)
    `dbName`.`surname`, -- varchar(50)

FROM `dbName`.`student`;
```

Table 2: **Course**

```
SELECT `dbName`.`id`, -- int
    `dbName`.`upload_dt`, -- date
    `dbName`.`end_of_dt`, -- date
    `dbName`.`coursename`, -- varchar(50)
    `dbName`.`coursedate`, -- date

FROM `dbName`.`course`;
```

Table 3: **StudentCourse**

```
SELECT `dbName`.`id`,  --int
    `dbName`.`upload_dt`, -- date
    `dbName`.`end_of_dt`, -- date
    `dbName`.`studentid`, -- int
    `dbName`.`courseid`,
FROM `dbName`.`studentcourse`;
```

**VIEW**

```
CREATE VIEW xyz
    SELECT student.id,
            student.upload_dt,
            student.end_of_dt,
            student.name
            student.surname
            course.coursename
            course.coursedate
    FROM Student 
Left JOIN StudentCourse
On student.id  = studentcourse.sid
Left JOIN Couse
On studentcourse.cid = course.id
```

I created a view in order to get the relevant data for my scenario, as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW xyz
SELECT <columns from 3 tables needed>
FROM Student 
Left JOIN StudentCourse
On student.id  = studentcourse.sid
Left JOIN Couse
On studentcourse.cid = course.id
```

When I try to see data using my view as follows it is taking me over 5minutes to get data

```
SELECT * FROM xyz
WHERE endDate = '2014-04'04'
```

I was thinking of adding an index on the column **endDate** which is coming from table Student, would this enhance performance?

Can anyone suggest anyway how I can optimize my view and enhance performance?

Comment: PS: currently I know that there are over 70,000 records that need to be displayed using this view

Comment: Can you post your table declares please? MySQL is poor at using indexes on views, and I suspect that with your query you are checking with the WHERE clause a field on the Course table, which would render using LEFT JOINs rather than INNER JOINs are not worthwhile.

Comment: edited question, hope this helps, please note that there are other columns in student and course

Comment: Do you have an index on studentid on the studentcourse table? I presume that that id on the course table is the primary key. Do you have an index on end_of_dt on the student table?

Comment: Currently there are no indexes setup, since in the view i am getting the student.end_of_dt, i was thinking of doing an index on it.  Would that help performance?

Comment: Views in MySQL are not good for indexes. Effectively they are just a sub query. While an index might help (and an index on studentid on the studentcourse table will certainly help) it may not. I generally avoid using views where performance is an issue.